# "Cannot set property 'color' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, colors, styles, undefined

I don't know why, but this code doesn't work...

I want the name "Yua" to be in a certain color when it appear in my HTML.

Every time, the console say: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined"

I've searched on many forums but I haven't found the answer to solve my problem!

```
var Yua = Object();
    Yua.Name = "Yua";
    Yua.Name.style.color = "#ffffff";
```

I also tried this:

```
var Yua = Object();
    Yua.Name = "Yua";
    var x = Yua.Name;
    x.style.color = "#ffffff";
```

I use an .innerHTML to display my text.

```
let tab_Scene_1_0 = 
    [
        true, 
        Yua.Name + ":  Hey!", 
        MC.Name + ":  Hey!"

    ];
//-------------------------------------------
var num = 1; 

document.getElementById("Dialogues").addEventListener("click", function() 
{

    if (tab_Scene_1_0[0] == true)
        {
            document.getElementById("line").innerHTML = "<p>" + tab_Scene_1_0[num] + "</p>"; 
            console.log(document.getElementById("line").innerHTML); 
            num += 1;
        }
```

I took a code found on internet to try the same thing, but on my computer it doesn't work either!

If anyone can help me, i would be very grateful!

Comment: `Yua.Name` is a simple JavaScript string value. Such values do not have a "style" property. You'll have to put the string in an HTML element (like a `<span>` perhaps) and then add rules to the element's `style` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
var element = document.createElement('p');
element.style.width = '330px';
element.style.float = 'left'
element.innerHTML = num; //Here are your values :)

document.getElementById("line").append(element);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! But I will rather use the <span> as Pointy said above, So I can use it more easily in my code!